# A characterization of functions which Riemannian Hessian equal to zero

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and measure distances in this space with some Riemannian metric $M(x)$. That is, for two points $x, y$, define $d(x, y)$ to be equal to
$$d(x, y) = \inf_{\gamma(\cdot) \in \Gamma_{x, y}}\sqrt{\int_0^1 \dot{\gamma}(s)^{\mathsf{T}}M(\gamma(s))\dot{\gamma}(s)ds},$$ where $\Gamma_{x, y}$ denotes the set of all curves over $[0, 1]$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$.

I'm interested in characterizing the set of "linear" functions with respect to this metric. That is, what are all functions that have Riemannian Hessian equal to zero in this metric? I understand that, on a compact Riemannian manifold, such functions are trivial. But what about a manifold with a single global chart as I've constructed here?

Comment: Existence of such a non-trivial function implies the existence of a parallel (non-zero) section of the cotangent bundle; this does not happen for generic Riemannian metrics.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What is the corresponding condition on the metric, for the kind of "Euclidean" space I've described?

Comment: If you have a non-constant function $f$ such that $\nabla^2 f \neq 0$, you have that its exterior differential $df$ is "covariantly constant" $\nabla df = 0$. This means that (a) $df \neq 0$ anywhere and (b) parallel transport of $df$ along _any closed loop_ returns you back to $df$. The latter condition states that your metric has [special holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy).  In particular, by the de Rham decomposition your manifold factors (locally) as a Cartesian product of a lower dimensional Euclidean space against something else.

Comment: The notation of Riemannian geometry is extremely standardized; you might prefer to call your Riemannian metric $g$. You don't need to explain what a Riemannian metric is on a mathematics research website. If we know what the Riemannian Hessian is, surely we know what a Riemannian metric is.